# Javascript if variable value equal to variable value

Tags: javascript

I have code like this in my website

```
var created = 10;
var limitacc = 25;
var element = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");

if (created.value === limitacc.value){
element.classList.add("bg-danger");
} else {
element.classList.add("bg-warning");
}
```

I want to change the bootstrap progress bar bg if created is same value in limitacc but the code is not working its stay in bg-warning even the created to 25

Comment: Have you tried to use `if (created === limitacc)`

Comment: if your goal is to dynamically change the color of your progress bar according to your 2 values, then your method here is not suitable

Comment: I only did == now i know i must use ===

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `.value`

```
var created = 10;
var limitacc = 25;
var element = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");

if (created=== limitacc){
element.classList.add("bg-danger");
} else {
element.classList.add("bg-warning");
}
```

Comment: It's work hehehe thanks bro by the way i did do the same this before but i use == but not work i wonder why  by the way thanks